# glMapBuffer and malloc

Tags: c, opengl

Here is an example code:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pboId[pboCounter]);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, dataSize, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
GLubyte* p = (GLubyte*)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

I have noticed that task manager(windows 10) shows increased memory usage after glMapBuffer call. I have read that glMapBuffer may use malloc or "memory mapping" ? It it an evidence that malloc has been used ? Does glMapBuffer may also use a memory mapping for the above scenario (GL_WRTIE_ONLY) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific details on how glMapBuffer works are left open to the OpenGL implementation being used. It may, or may not use an additional shadow allocation.

However you must be careful about interpreting the number reported by Windows' "Task Manager": The number it reports in plain sight is the amount of address space allocated, not the actual amount of memory being used; the later can be much, much smaller.

> Does glMapBuffer may also use a memory mapping for the above scenario (GL_WRTIE_ONLY)?

Yes of course.

Comment: Could you please explain how memory mapping works for such scenario ? Let's assume that I have 32 bit process with 2GB memory limit. Some amount of the process memory is initially reserved by the opengl driver. Due to memory fragmentation I can't call malloc with a block size specified in glBufferData (it returns null). Is it possible that glMapBuffer will work somehow ?

Comment: @Irbis: If the `glMapBuffer` happens to map a piece of buffer, for that's there already a shadow buffer allocated, then all it does is return a pointer to that, and increase a reference counter; no new memory or address space must be allocated then. But if there's no contiguous region of address space left to map a new allocation or DMA region, then the mapping will fail.

Comment: However if your program suffers from heavy memory fragmentation, you're doing "something" wrong. Normal malloc should operate from a preallocated buffer region. Could it, by perchance be, that you're creating lots of small OpenGL buffer objects? One for each piece of geometry you want to draw? If so, don't do that. Allocate a large buffer object from which you slice subsets for your data, and use appropriate offsets when setting the vertex attribute pointers.

Comment: So the memory mapping takes place in the 2GB memory which is available for the process or glMapBuffer may return a pointer to the memory which is located outside the process ?

Comment: @Irbis: Of course any mapping must take place inside the address space of the process. How do you imagine would a pointer of limited size be able to point outside of the value range it can take on. A process address space is literally just an enumeration of all bytes from 0 to `${WHATEVER_THE_MAXIMUM_VALUE_OF_A_POINTER_IS}`. There are no "magic" pointers of "imaginary" numbers, that are capable to point into wonderland.